# SQL Server - SQL Agent Alerts - Alert 824 warning about old problems

Tags: sql-server, corruption

I have alerts enabled on a SQL Server 2017 where corruption was encountered and repaired over a year ago. I have also confirmed that there is no new corruption on any database on this server.

When restarting the SQL Server it sends out an error 824 alert message that states the following:

> DATE/TIME:  1/17/2019 7:54:22 PM
>
> DESCRIPTION: SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O
>   error: incorrect checksum (expected: 0xe660dd36; actual: 0xcd481907).
>   It occurred during a read of page (1:386939) in database ID 7 at
>   offset 0x000000bcef6000 in file 'C:\DATA\database.mdf'.  Additional
>   messages in the SQL Server error log or operating system error log may
>   provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens
>   database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full
>   database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by
>   many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.

The issue here is that the date/time is from 11 months ago. What I am looking for is details on what the alert for error 824 is checking or what needs to be purged from 11 months ago to prevent this false positive alert from being sent out.

- I have checked msdb.dbo.suspect_pages - there are no entries in that table.
- All SQL server logs have rotate out in that time period so it is not something in the log.
- I have ran checkDB a couple of times to confirm no new corruption.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this is an agent alert, if so you could try to right click on the alert -> properties -> History and check the 'Reset count' box and it should clear out.